# SQL query takes too long to run, asp.net stops responding

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query that takes about ~10 minutes to complete, the result of this query is being shown on an asp.net webpage.

The problem here is that when I run the query on SQL Server it works fine, but when the query is fired from the web-page, no result is shown on the webpage.

The database size is about ~9 GB, and contains more than 10 million records.

Any solution that would make my webpage wait for the query to be completed and the result being displayed on the page.

The webpage should wait until the response from SQL Server is received - NO termination of connection from SQL Server until the result is received, and the webpage should wait that long.

The Query that is being used is

```
SELECT
  [Ageing_old].[dbo].[base].[Acct Ext Id]
FROM
  [Ageing_old].[dbo].[base] 
     INNER JOIN [Ageing].[dbo].[Base_Adj_Apr_Dec] ON [Ageing_old].[dbo].[base].[Acct Ext Id] = [Ageing].[dbo].[Base_Adj_Apr_Dec].[Billable Ext Id]
     INNER JOIN [Ageing].[dbo].[Base_Payment] ON [Ageing_old].[dbo].[base].[Acct Ext Id] = [Ageing].[dbo].[Base_Payment].[BILLED_ID]     
     INNER JOIN [Ageing].[dbo].[Base_POD] ON [Ageing_old].[dbo].[base].[Acct Ext Id] = [Ageing].[dbo].[Base_POD].[Acct No]  
     INNER JOIN [Ageing].[dbo].[Billing_Base_1] ON [Ageing_old].[dbo].[base].[Acct Ext Id] = [Ageing].[dbo].[Billing_Base_1].[ext_account_no]   
     WHERE [Ageing_old].[dbo].[base].[Acct Ext Id] IN (
        SELECT Distinct [Ageing].[dbo].[mobile_to_acct].[EXTERNAL_ID]        
        FROM [Ageing].[dbo].[mobile_to_acct],[Ageing].[dbo].[Devices_Base]
        INNER JOIN [Ageing].[dbo].[Final_MNP] ON [Ageing].[dbo].[Devices_Base].[ACCESS_METHOD_IDENTIFIER]= [Ageing].[dbo].[Final_MNP].[MSISDN]
        INNER JOIN [Ageing].[dbo].[FTR_Dec] ON [Ageing].[dbo].[Devices_Base].[ACCESS_METHOD_IDENTIFIER]= [Ageing].[dbo].[FTR_Dec].[Sinumber]
        INNER JOIN [Ageing].[dbo].[SR_Dec] ON [Ageing].[dbo].[Devices_Base].[ACCESS_METHOD_IDENTIFIER]= [Ageing].[dbo].[SR_Dec].[SI_NUMBER]
     )
```

Comment: Are you saying that you want to display 10 million records on the web page? If so, that's not a good thing because rendering 10 million records will take a lot more time after the sql query is finished. Perhaps you should consider to use paging.

Comment: the database contains 10 Million records, the Sql query works on those records.

Max amount of records that i would display would be around 100

Comment: I would look to optimising your query. If it takes 10 minutes to get the data, then there are likely HUGE efficiency increases that could be made. We'd need to see your Query/Schema to understand what could help.

Comment: Please show us the sql query and some code that fires the query.

Comment: The problem here is not with the query, its how can i make the asp page wait till the result of the query is processed.

still here's the query that i am running

Comment: As others have mentioned already, you shouldn't try to hack the timeout, but rather optimize the SQL.. 10min query is just insanity and it doesn't matter that it's working on 10mil records. You have probably some seriously flawed SQL logic going on...The problem is exactly with the query, not with the page. No user should wait 10min for a single sql query...

Comment: If you really can't optimise your query, you should consider an AJAX callback to kick off the query and then you could poll at set intervals to check for completion (better than postback and wait). You may also want to consider running the query async so you are not blocking asp.net worker threads.

Comment: Don't post it as a comment, who would read that! Update your question instead please.

Comment: As a very first optimisation, you could remove that distinct in your 'IN', as it's totally unnecessary...

Comment: You have an unconstrained join in your sub select: `mobile_to_acct` is not actually linked to `Devices_Base` or any other item in the select. Thats going to cause a heap of duplicate records. Is that deliberate?

Comment: Also, you are performing a heap of joins, but only returning data from base. and only filtering on data in base. Why are the other joins required?

Comment: that join has been applied to map the contents of [mobile] field to [acct] field.

Tables [Base_Adj_Apr_Dec], [Base_Payment], [Base_POD], [Billing_Base_1] and [base] have one (id) field common 

Tables [Final_MNP], [FTR_Dec], [SR_Dec], [Devices_Base] have another field(number) common 

[mobile_to_acct] is used to map [id] to [number]

Comment: This is just the sample query, fields from other tables will also be fetched

Comment: @Paddy, Tried it, hardly any difference

Comment: You could set the server timeout figure to a high enough value that it will not time out. But like other people have said finding some way to get this data quicker would be better. You could even cache the results in another table and set something up to have that results table populate when required.

Comment: How to change the wait and execution time of the server ?